# Warning: treating 'c-header' input as 'c++-header' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated

Tags: c++, clang

What does this clang++ error message mean, and why am I getting it? I can't seem to find *anything* on the internet about it...
`clang: warning: treating 'c-header' input as 'c++-header' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated`

Here's my code,

**MergeSort.h**:

```
#ifndef __MERGESORT_H__
#define __MERGESORT_H__

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MergeSort;

class MergeSort
{
    public:

    MergeSort();
    MergeSort(const int* list, int length);
    ~MergeSort();

    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const MergeSort& ms);

    private:

    int* list;
    int len;
};

ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const MergeSort& ms);
#endif
```

**MergeSort.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "MergeSort.h"

using namespace std;

MergeSort::MergeSort()
{
    list = new int[1];
    list[0] = 0;
    len = 0;
}

MergeSort::MergeSort (const int* t, int length)
{
    if (t) {
        len = length;
        list = new int[len];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            list[i] = t[i];
    }
    else {
        list = new int[1];
        list[0] = 0;
        len = 0;
    }
}

MergeSort::~MergeSort()
{
    delete[] list;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const MergeSort& ms)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ms.len; i++)
        os << ms.list[i];
    return os;
}


int
main()
{
    int list[] = {1,2,3,4};
    int list_len = sizeof(list)/sizeof(int);
    MergeSort ms = MergeSort(list, list_len);
    cout << ms << endl;
    cout << "hello world" << endl;
}
```

And the output:

```
[gyeh@gyeh mergesort]$ clang++ -c -g -Wall MergeSort.cpp MergeSort.h
clang: warning: treating 'c-header' input as 'c++-header' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated
[gyeh@gyeh mergesort]$ clang++ MergeSort.o -o MergeSort
[gyeh@gyeh mergesort]$ valgrind --leak-check=yes ./MergeSort
==25774== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==25774== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==25774== Using Valgrind-3.9.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==25774== Command: ./MergeSort
==25774== 
1234
hello world
==25774== 
==25774== HEAP SUMMARY:
==25774==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==25774==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 16 bytes allocated
==25774== 
==25774== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==25774== 
==25774== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==25774== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 1 from 1)
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You should not compile the *header files*, only the source files.

Comment: So the command line should be just: `clang++ -c -g -Wall MergeSort.cpp` (not mentioning `MergeSort.h` directly).

Comment: *sigh*... thank you, the error message makes much more sense now.

Comment: What about precompiling headers?

Comment: It also occurs when trying to build dependencies: `make depend`.

Comment: @jayatubi Precompiled headers is something completely different, and works differently depending on compiler.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I encounted this issue because the Android NDK clang toolchain was going to use `clang++` command to generate the `pch` file from the original `prefix.h` file. Do you know what is the proper way to deal with the PCH in the new world?

Comment: @jayatubi Unfortunately I don't have that enough experience with precompiled header using GCC or Clang.

Answer (score 19):

Inspire from @JoachimPileborg. The actually meaning of this error message tells is:

You're compiling an `C` header file via a `CXX` compiler. It `DOES NOT` mean you `CAN NOT` compile the *header* files. you `CAN` compile the *header* file if you choose the right compiler for the right files. In simple words:

```
clang   with *.h    works
clang   with *.hpp  not works
clang++ with *.h    not works
clang++ with *.hpp  works
```

So to fix the issue about compiling the header files, for example the pre-compile headers, just change the suffix from `.h` to `.hpp` will do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

In the very rare case that you actually want to compile/parse/tokenise a C++ header file, you can pass the `-x c++-header` command line flag to clang++, like so:

```
clang++ -x c++-header header.h
```

There's a number of rare but valid reasons why you'd want to compile or at least tokenise/parse header files using clang, and this will silence the deprecation warning.

This info can be found via the `clang++ --help` docs.

```
$ clang++ --help
#
# ... other help details
#
  -x <language>           Treat subsequent input files as having type <language>
```

Comment: Probably the most common use-case is making a PCH.

Comment: Here is another [(rare) use case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71471967/clangd-treat-files-with-non-standard-extensions-as-headers), for IDE annotations using clangd.